# Why WebGL build disables Mouse Wheel Scroll on webpage?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have unity2D Game running in a canvas on Website(WebGL Build).When scrolling the page, scrolling stops when the mouse gets over the webGL content.

I want to enable Mouse Scroll on WebGL content.After a lot of research on Google, I found a solution in HTML.

```
style:

#gameContainer{pointer-events:none; }

html:
<div id="gameContainer" ></div>  

And

void Start ()
{
    #if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
    WebGLInput.captureAllKeyboardInput = false;    
    #endif
}
```

It worked partially.It just enabled the page scroll on WebGL content but disabled all other Mouse Events including Click event.Is there any workaround at least ?enter code here

The above code doesn't provide any results.I will be happy to know, the reason why webGL canvas is not responding to Mouse Scroll in Browser.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want to disable mouse and keyboard inputs in your player at all?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html